# Creating a Pronounciation Checker for specific words using CNN-RNN machine learning in flask

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, flask, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm someone who have a basic idea on how machine learning works and I just got to flask as well. I'm trying to create a system where its main feature wherein the user will input or record their own voice and the system will tell whether their pronunciation is correct or incorrect. I made my own neural network already. Basically, the word is already selected and I want the system to check if that specific word that the user will say is correct in pronunciation. Can you guys tell me what to do or atleast what to learn? I'm kind of lost atm. Thank you!

I've tried doing it myself and trying to find tutorials about it but sadly, I cannot see anything that is closely related to what I'm trying to achieve